# Odd Magento Admin User

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, user

i am using Magento CE 1.9.1.0 and i just noticed an admin account called _auto_update with an email of auto_update@magento.com . I never created this user and i dont recall it being there when i downloaded and installed magento. I didnt install any modules recently and none of the modules i previously installed did this. I only applied the needed security patches to this installation and nothing else. Where did this user come from? P.S i have a test website is just about identical to this production website but this user does not exist

Comment: May be your site hacked....have you use latest security patches.. please take all backup of magento db and files and after delete that user. and apply security patches

Comment: Ya thats what im thinking but i've applied all the needed security patches, i have 5994 and 5344 applied but 1533 didnt apply, i saw somewhere that is already applied to magento v1.9.1. Also the store passes the shoplyft bug test.

Comment: If you tried to apply 1533 and it didn't apply, crack open the patch file and check why it didn't apply. I removed the downloader files from my install which causes one of the patches to fail auto patching, so I had to do it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no auto update feature and certainly no auto update that requires a magento admin user. So you have been hacked. Likely before you applied the patches.

There are many guides on stack exchange that explain what to do in this case.